# How to hide navigation bar in Android 11+ react-native Modals?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to have my react native app immersive (no navigation bar displayed).

I successfully managed to get rid of it in most of my app screen by adding this in my `MainActivity.java`:

```java
  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    // Code for immersive mode (cannot be called in onCreate on Android 11 or it would crash as view not ready)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
      hideNavAndroid11();
    }
    else {
      hideNavAndroid10();

      // Step 2
      getWindow().getDecorView()
        .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View
        .OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
              if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0 ||
                  (visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) == 0) {
                  hideNavAndroid10();
              }
          }
      });
    }

    super.onStart();
  }


  @Override
  public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        hideNavAndroid10();
      }
  }

  public void hideNavAndroid11() {
    final Window view = getWindow();
    try {
      runOnUiThread(
        () -> {
          WindowInsetsController insetsController = view.getInsetsController();

          if (insetsController != null) {
            insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars());
            insetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
          }
        }
      );
    } catch (IllegalViewOperationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void hideNavAndroid10() {
     try {
      runOnUiThread(
        () -> {
          final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
          decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            // View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | // if I do that, I get a margin of nav bar height at the bottom
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hides nav bar
            // | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hides status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
          );
        }
      );
    } catch (IllegalViewOperationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Despite this, on Android > 11, every time a react-native `Modal` / `Alert` / Soft keyboard shows up, it has the Android navigation bar displayed.

How can I get rid of it on Modals, Alerts, and soft keyboard?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? We are also stuck with this issue.

Comment: Nope :(... I think that it would require to add support for this in the native android code of the Modal RN component...